# SQL Server 2005 linked server, no tables showing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I've followed the guides shown online for creating linked servers, I've attempted it multiple times and I've gone over all the usual suspects like user permissions but they all seem alright. But no matter what I do, I only get a linked server icon in object explorer, there are no tables under it or anything at all really.

I can run queries such as

```
Select * FROM Fakt000...art
```

or

```
sp_tables _ex N'Fakt000'
```

both of these works and will return the proper data, but nothing is still seen in the object explorer window.

My desired end result from this would have been that I could have accessed this database in an identical manner to a normal SQL Server database via VS2010.

Comment: Have you refreshed the object explorer?

Comment: I have done that yes, it did not work.

Comment: Are both servers MS SQL servers?

Comment: There is only one server and it's an MS SQL server, the access file I am trying to connect to is located on the same computer as the SQL server as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This forum thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic565482-6-5.aspx#bm936680) might be helpful; if you haven't already make sure your Access database is set to use **logon** rather than database password.